# Major conjectures used to prove complexity lower bounds?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds

Complexity theory uses a large number of unproven conjectures. There are several hardness conjectures in David Johnson's [NP-Completeness Column 25](http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/columns/col25.pdf). What are the other major conjectures not mentioned in the above article? Did we achieve some progress towards proving one of these conjectures? Which conjecture do you think would require completely different techniques from the currently known ones?

Comment: what's the question ? the article has a long list anyway. Provide a link for the column, please.

Comment: And at the very least, this should be "community wiki".

Comment: The term "complexity lower bounds" means in many (or most?) occasions unconditional lower bounds (like circuit size lower bounds). So the question is unclear.

Comment: Please make it CW if required.

Comment: The current question (revision 4) is much more interesting than the previous revisions, but it is broad.  I think that you are putting too many things in one question.

Answer (score 5):

The unique games conjecture has recently been one of the most fruitful assumptions for proving good lower bounds, although it is more controversial than most assumptions about complexity class separation.  See [On the Unique Games Conjecture](http://cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/UGCSurvey.pdf) for a list of consequences.

Comment: UGC is very nice, but I am not sure if this answer fits the question.  I do not think that the term “complexity lower bound” usually includes hardness based on reducibility such as NP-hardness or UG-hardness.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't mentioned in the article, but the [exponential time hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) is very useful for proving exponential lower bounds on the running time of hard problems.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial hierarchy is infinite. This implies other conjectures that are often used, like NP is not in coAM, NP is not equal to coNP, etc.